# Using jquery with django

Tags: jquery, django

I'm building an eshop. I have a page where i present products of a certain category and the default sorting of the products is by newest.I have a dropdown select menu with some options(newest, price-from high to low, best sellers.If the costumer selects the best sellers option i want the part of the page that presents the products to be refreshed so that the products are now sorted by best sellers.
Whats the most efficient way to do this? Should i use the load() function or what?
Any sources on the web or books that i could read about this sort of problems?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few jquery plugins for sorting and otherwise manipulating tables. 
Some hints:

- http://www.google.de/search?q=jquery+sort+table
- http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-great-jquery-plugins-for-better-table-manipulation/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define what you mean by efficient.

jQuery offers a variety of functions to deal with Ajax. Some are shortcuts for simple straightforward tasks - `load()` is one such function - while others offer more options and require a bit more code, like `jQuery.ajax()`.

Here's a list of all the different functions: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Hope that helps.